# Python pandas split a number in two parts and attach in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

have a df with values

```
a       b
tom    9812357837
matt   1325478227
```

how to split the first four and last four columns of columns b and add last 4 digits in first and first four digits at last

1325478227

number =1325478227 ,  first_four=1325  , last_four=8227

new number =  last_four + number + first_four

expected output:

```
a       b                  c
tom    9812357837       783798123578379812
matt   1325478227       822713254782271325
```

Answer (score 2):

Check

```
s = df.b.astype(str)
df['New']= pd.to_numeric(s.str[-4:]+s+s.str[:4])
df
Out[219]: 
      a           b                 New
0   tom  9812357837  783798123578379812
1  matt  1325478227  822713254782271325
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split on word boundry with `\B`, you do:

```
df['c'] = (df['b']
           .astype(str)
           .str
           .split('\B')
           .apply(lambda x: x[-4:] + x + x[:4]).str.join(''))

print(df)

      a           b                   c
0   tom  9812357837  783798123578379812
1  matt  1325478227  822713254782271325
```